# Mount Raspbian Jessie in local filesystem fails

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, mount, linux-mint

I am trying without success to mount a clean Raspbain Jessie image downloaded directly from raspberrypi.org into my local Linux Mint filesystem:

```
sudo mount 2016-03-18-raspbian-jessie.img -o offset=62914560 /mnt/rpi/
```

but this command is returning me:

```
mount you must specify the filesystem type
```

I have tried to add -t vfat and -t ext4 without success.

**Note:** several months ago i did this without problems and without -t parameter in other Linux Mint version.

What i am doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a raw image file like that, rather than trying to guess the offset of a partition it's easiest just to do this first:

```
$ sudo losetup -fP --show 2016-03-18-raspbian-jessie.img
/dev/loop1
```

The `-P` option to `losetup` causes it to scan the image for partitions, and create the appropriate devices:

```
$ ls /dev/loop1*
/dev/loop1  /dev/loop1p1  /dev/loop1p2  /dev/loop1p5
```

The `-f` option asks `losetup` to find a free loop device, and `--show` asks it to show you the loop device on `stdout`.

And now you can just mount one of the partitions, e.g.:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/loop1p1 /mnt
```

When you're done:

```
$ sudo umount /mnt
$ sudo losetup -d /dev/loop1
```

Comment: Ok, i have found that my offset was wrong, the correct one for raspbian jessie is: sudo mount 2016-03-18-raspbian-jessie.img -o offset=4194304 /mnt/rpi/